# A-Frame 0.9.0 Appears to be Broken

Tags: aframe

this glitch page runs a scene in A-Frame version 0.9.0 from 
`https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js`

https://glitch.com/~aframe-scenestarter-iam

if you change the version to 0.9.2 - or the new 1.0.0 - you can see what it's supposed to look like. Hell, 0.7.0 looks right, just the animation breaks

**Just days ago** the 0.9.0 version was working and no changes were made to it in the mean time...

ALL MY A-FRAME SCENES are likewise broken overnight!

They also all log error messages in the console. They appear to vary, but here's the error from this page

```
`Uncaught TypeError: navigator.xr.requestDevice is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (device.js:5)
at Object.176._process (device.js:141)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.179../bind (index.js:6)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at _prelude.js:1
at Object.152.../package (index.js:25)
at o (_prelude.js:1)
at r (_prelude.js:1)`
```

I have several hundred A-Frame scenes relying on 0.9.0 and I'm in deep into a jobsearch -can anyone help?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4354#issuecomment-567052948) out

Answer (score 2):

The new WebXR standard is shipping now in Chrome and Oculus browsers. The old WebVR API has been deprecated, that’s why you are seeing those errors. All sites have to update to A-Frame 1.0.1 or newer to keep working. Your example using 1.0.1: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/puffy-caravel?path=index.html:19:47

Comment: I will, of course, update my hundreds of scenes. But why then does 0.7.0 work (without, of course, animation) and 0.9.2 work? what caused catastrophic, across-the-board failure of ONLY 0.9.0?

Comment: Because 0.9.2 had support for a previous iteration of the WebXR standard and calls a method that no longer exists in the final spec. 0.7.0 predates all WebXR work.

Comment: 0.7.0 might work in 2D mode but VR mode no longer works. I encourage updating to 1.0.1

Answer (score -1):

This *should* work, but try using

```
http://%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@333873f3279c8d49881577662e16e51baa480ea3/dist/aframe-master.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E
```

as your a-frame script. If it does not work, I would suggest waiting for an update on this. I have a friend who's animations broke, however mine did not.

Comment: your link seems to be broken

Comment: @IAM I believe it is fixed now